# How to sort markers on a given layer alphabetically

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to making maps on Google Maps so forgive the noob question. I am in the process of creating a map for all the fire stations in the LA Area. (https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=zOj-A9yhD48A.kNo71D1gETvs)

One of the layers, titled `LACoFD` has a number of stations listed but they are not in order. I would really like them to be in alphabetical order. I tried opening the datatable in MapMaker in chrome and managed to sort the data but that was not reflected in the list on the left. Is there an easy way to do this? Also, should I be using something other than just the web browser to edit this data? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way.

You'll need to sort them manually via drag&drop in the list on the left.

Answer (score 1):

This problem needs a work-around.

When listed un-ordered alphabetically there is no way to sort the stations/markers.
First you have to choose to convert the display of the markers to numbers, then you can drag and drop them and change the numeric order. 
Then you can choose to display them as markers again.

Answer (score 0):

I exported the list as a .csv file and converted this list into a sheets file.
As a sheets file, the names column can be used to sort the file alphabetically.
Now it has to be converted back into a .csv file so it can be imported back into the Google My Maps app. However, the format the app wants is three columns, one latitude, one with longitude and one with the marker name. What you have at the moment are two columns, one with POINT(lat, long) and the next with the marker name. So select the position column and erase POINT( and ) to leave just lat, long. Then split the lat, long column into two columns, one with lat and one with long. Now convert this sheets file into a .csv file

Delete the original marker layer in the Google My Maps app, create a new layer and import the .csv file with the marker information, now sorted alphabetically

It is a long winded work-around, but if you have a list of a 70 marker points or so, definitely quicker than sorting by hand.